# How can I call my .ashx handler to retrieve my Facebook token?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am new to Web handlers. Here is the handler taken basically from the tutorial www.facebooksdk.net.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PogoTrip
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FacebookLogin1
/// </summary>
public class FacebookLogin : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request["accessToken"];
        context.Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        context.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

}

And then here is the code that I am using to try and retrieve the token:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
        var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic me = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
    }
```

I can't figure out how to actually reference the .ashx file (I think that is the problem anyways

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need to access the ASHX file, because that code placed the token into session.  Are you certain that the handler is wired up correctly in WebConfig?  Have you confirmed that the handler is firing?  What makes you think that every request will include "accessToken" in the context?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding. Could I do this without the ASHX file altogether? I don't think the handler is firing, that's the problem. Every user has an accessToken (they will have to allow access to get the app), is that what you mean? And what would I need to do to the WebConfig? this could be the problem

Comment: In webconfig, you need to wire up your handler, explaining what URL it will get fired on and what code will be executed.  See this article on the basics of ASHX handlers http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx.  Yes, you could do away with the handler altogether if you just wanted your page to handle the details of pulling out the access token.